# Filter records in XML using XSLT after occurrence of certain values

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, xslt-1.0

I am getting below sample xml and I want to fetch all `<Student>` nodes between starting value **`<TransactionCode>`**8**`</TransactionCode>`**
**`<RecordType>`**5**`</RecordType>`**   &  ending value **`<TransactionCode>`**9**`</TransactionCode>` `<RecordType>`**5**`</RecordType>`**

Sample XML

```
<element>
<Student>
<Name>Sam</Name>
<TransactionCode>8</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>5</RecordType>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>bob</Name>
<TransactionCode>3</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>1</RecordType>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Don</Name>
<TransactionCode>9</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>5</RecordType>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Mike</Name>
<TransactionCode>8</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>5</RecordType>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Jhony</Name>
<TransactionCode>2</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>1</RecordType>
</Student>
<Student>
<Name>Alan</Name>
<TransactionCode>9</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>5</RecordType>
</Student>
 </element>
```

> 

**Expected output**

```
<element>
<Student>
<Name>bob</Name>
<TransactionCode>3</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>1</RecordType>
<Student>
<Name>Jhony</Name>
<TransactionCode>2</TransactionCode>
<RecordType>1</RecordType>
</Student>
</element>
```

Please help how can be done using xslt as I am new to xslt .

Comment: You want to filter (select all <STUDENTRECORDIDENTITY> that matches) or select a range of <STUDENTRECORDIDENTITY> from a record that match to one that does not match? Please clarifty. Possibly use a simpler example...

Comment: Yes I want to filer all <STUDENTRECORDIDENTITY> that matched condition.

I have edited query with simpler example .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a good XSL Sudoku!

When you make your XPath, remember that multiple [] conditions are logically joined with "and", so //element[x][y][z] mean all elements with x, y and z children.

Applying this your case, use 3 clauses.

First, skip the 8 and 9

```
[not(TransactionCode=8 or TransactionCode=9)]
```

Next, make sure the Student has a preceding sibling with a good value

```
[preceding-sibling::Student[TransactionCode=8][RecordType=5]]
```

Then, make sure the Student has a following sibling with a good value

```
[following-sibling::Student[TransactionCode=9][RecordType=5]]
```

Finally, to ensure that you don't match a student that occurs "between" a start and stop element, only output if there's more start elements that closing elements.

Assembled all together.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <!-- This would still be a TON of code in JSON!  Thanks XSL! -->
    <xsl:template match='/'>
        <element>
            <xsl:for-each select='//Student [not(TransactionCode=8 or TransactionCode=9)]
                [preceding-sibling::Student[TransactionCode=8][RecordType=5]]
                [following-sibling::Student[TransactionCode=9][RecordType=5]]
            '>
                <!--  Edit, - prevent finding students that occure after a stop element but before the next start element -->
                <xsl:variable name='startcount' select='count(preceding-sibling::Student[TransactionCode=8][RecordType=5])'/>
                <xsl:variable name='stopcount' select='count(preceding-sibling::Student[TransactionCode=9][RecordType=5])'/>
    
                <xsl:if test='$startcount &gt; $stopcount'>
                    <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </element>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That will also select nodes that are in-between the groups. There are no such nodes in the given example, but ...

Comment: Yes, but only Student nodes that match all the conditions.  OP mentions they want "all Students between starting and ending value", so I think it's still good.  What case do you have in mind?

Comment: A case where a Student is between ending and starting value.

Comment: I tried pretty much the same thing yesterday but it does not work when there are Student elements that are before any Student[TransactionCode=9][RecordType=5] and that are after the first preceding-sibling::Student[TransactionCode=8][RecordType=5]. See the fiddle I had here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxr/0

Comment: Good point guys, I added code to count up the start and stop elements, and only output if there are more starts than stops. Works on Students that occur after a ending value and before a starting value (thx michael)

Comment: Thanks a lot @WilliamWalseth and everyone for help , the xslt  exactly worked what I was looking .